# Socket.io событие срабатывает несколько раз

Tags: node.js, vue.js, socket.io

Пишу чат с использованием vue-socket.io-extended.
Событие 'add message' срабатывает несколько раз при повторном вызывании. Также сообщения других пользователей начинают появляться только, когда пользователь напишет в чат.
Сервер:

```
 const connections = [];

    io.sockets.on('connection', socket => {
        connections.push(socket);

    socket.on('send message', data => {
        io.sockets.emit('add message', { userId: data.userId, username: data.username, text: data.text, date: data.date });
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', socket => {
        connections.splice(connections.indexOf(socket), 1);
    });
});
```

Клиент:

```
<template>
    <div class="chat-container">
        <div class="chat-messages">
            <div :class="{
                    'chat-messages-mine': $store.getters.getUser.id === message.userId,
                    'chat-messages-stranger': $store.getters.getUser.id !== message.userId
                }"
                v-for="message in messages">
                <div class="chat-messages-name">{{ message.username }}:</div>
                <div class="chat-messages-text">{{ message.text }}</div>
                <div class="chat-messages-time">{{ message.date }}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="chat-interface">
            <textarea class="chat-interface-text" v-model="text"></textarea>
            <button @click="sendMessage">Сообщить</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<style lang="scss">
    .chat {
        &-container {
            padding: 1em;
            border: 1px solid #000;
            border-left: none;
        }

        &-messages {
            min-height: 600px;
            max-height: 600px;
            overflow: auto;
            padding: 1em;
            background-color: #451705;
            color: #fff;
            margin-bottom: 1em;

            &-stranger,
            &-mine {
                display: grid;
                grid-template-columns: 10% 80% 10%;
                grid-auto-rows: 100px;
                grid-gap: 1em;
                justify-items: center;
                align-items: center;
                margin: 1em;
                position: relative;
                color: #969494;

                &:before {
                    content: "";
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 2px;
                    background-color: #fff;
                    position: absolute;
                    bottom: 0;
                }
            }

            &-mine {
                color: #fff;
            }

            &-text {
                width: 100%;
                word-wrap: break-word;
            }
        }

        &-interface {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 80% 20%;

            &-text {
                background-color: #451705;
                outline: none;
                border: none;
                padding: .5em 1em;
                resize: none;
                color: #fff;
                font-family: 'Ruslan Display', cursive;
            }

            button {
                font-family: 'Ruslan Display', cursive;
                background-color: #803F06;
                color: #FCDC06;
                outline: none;
                border: none;
                transition: .2s;
                cursor: pointer;

                &:hover {
                    background-color: #451705;
                }
            }
        }
    }
</style>
<script>
export default {
    name: 'Chat',
    data() {
        return {
            messages: [],
            text: ''
        }
    },
    methods: {
        sendMessage() {
            const messageData = {
                userId: this.$store.getters.getUser.id,
                username: this.$store.getters.getUser.username,
                text: this.text,
                date: `${new Date().getHours()}:${new Date().getMinutes()}`
            }

            this.$socket.client.emit('send message', messageData);
            this.$socket.client.on('add message', data => {
                this.messages.push(data);
            });

            this.text = '';
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: может потому что событие this.$socket.client.on('add message') у вас вешается при отправке сообщения? не думали перенести его из функции к глобальный контекст ? и хочу замтить что вы создаете новый слушатель события каждый раз при отправке сообщения и чем больше сообщений вы отправите без перезагрузки страницы - столько и будет дубликатов сообщений, каждый обработчик который вы создали будет добавлять сообщение в чат, `this.$socket.client.on('add message',...` данный код должен вызыватся единожды на странице

Answer (score 0):

Проблема заключается в том что при каждом вызове функции `sendMessage` у вас создается новый слушатель события `add message`, что ведет за собой при вызове `add message` обработку полученного сообщения всеми обработчиками который создавались при каждой отправке и каждый из них делает `this.messages.push(data);` - вот и причина дублирования сообщений. Данный участок кода:

```js
this.$socket.client.on('add message', data => {
  this.messages.push(data);
});
```

должен вызываться единожды на странице например после подключения к сокету.

Проблема с получением сообщений только при отправке  скорее всего скрыта в этом же, вы  обращаетесь к messages с `this` которого не существует в контексте `callback` функции на момент ее вызова, что вызывает ошибку и естественно не добавляет сообщение. Если вы хотите так делать то `this` в таком случае нужно заранее сохранить в какой-либо глобальной переменной и заменить `this.messages.push(data);` на `myGlobalVarible.messages.push(data);`, где `myGlobalVarible` - ваша переменная в которую вы скопировали ссылку на объект `this`.